# angular controllers, multiple templates, and passing scope values from controllers to master page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting a new project and am going to be using angular in a "single page architecture" application.  I'm a little new to angular.

So, I purchased a template for my site.  It has 2 distinct layouts that I would like to use.  1 for my unauthenticated (marketing) pages and another for most of my authenticated pages.

The difference in each is subtle, but the inside pages require a class on the `<body>` tags that the outside pages cannot have.  I considered using 2 layouts but then that got tricky as I started thinking about how I would lay out my urls.

My thought is to use angular to manage my layout so that I only need one master page like this:

```
<body ng-class="{menu-right-hidden: isInternalPage }">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div ng-if="isInternalPage" id="menu" class="hidden-print hidden-xs sidebar-blue sidebar-brand-primary">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div ng-if="isInternalPage" id="footer" class="hidden-print">
        <!-- internal footer -->
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!isInternalPage" id="footer" class="hidden-print">
        <!-- external footer -->
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

My question is this: Is there an easy way to set `isInternalPage` (and possibly other valies) without having `$scope.isInternalPage = true/false;` decorating all of my controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ng-init and define a scope variable on $rootScope:

```
<body ng-init="$root.isInternalPage = true" ng-class="{menu-right-hidden: $root.isInternalPage }">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div ng-if="$root.isInternalPage" id="menu" class="hidden-print hidden-xs sidebar-blue sidebar-brand-primary">
        <!-- sidebar content -->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div ng-if="$root.isInternalPage" id="footer" class="hidden-print">
        <!-- internal footer -->
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!$root.isInternalPage" id="footer" class="hidden-print">
        <!-- external footer -->
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Alternatively, you could assign your variable on $rootScope inside one of your controllers:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isInternalPage = true;
});
```

Comment: I really like this idea, but I think I will expand this to wrap this variable in a service (as suggested by @aarosil) in case I need other values available on the master page, and to standardize it across my controllers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is create an AngularJS [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services): "You can use services to organize and share code across your app"

```
angular.module('core').service('GlobalVars', [ 'addDependenciesHere',
    function(addDependenciesHere) {
        this.isInternalPage = someVal ? true : false 
    }
]);
```

Then inject this into the constructor for each controller

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'GlobalVars', 
    function ($scope, GlobalVars) {
        $scope.globals = GlobalVars;
    }
]);
```

Then in your view you can access this directly

```
<body ng-class="{menu-right-hidden: globals.isInternalPage }">
```